# Java aes decryption bytebuffer including padding as null bytes

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am trying to migrate an encryption code that was encrypting a byte[] to a bytebuffer in order to integrate better with another apis.

The previous code using byte[8] works fine, where the output of the decryption is exactly the unencrypted byte[8].

However, when migrated to bytebuffer, the decrypted bytebuffer is a bytebuffer not of the size of the original message, but the original message + padding,  being  the space defined by padding as null.

Is there a good way to have decryption result identical as the input.

The code uses the transformation *AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding*

```
//this gives the maximum size, including the possible padding, not the real size
int outputSize = cipher.getOutputSize(input.remaining());

ByteBuffer output = ByteBuffer.allocate(outputSize);

cipher.doFinal(input, output);

return output.rewind().asReadOnlyBuffer();
```

Comment: i have limited the output bytebuffer for the time being only, as i could not figure out a way to determine the right outputsize before hand.

```output.limit(output.position()).rewind().asReadOnlyBuffer();```

Comment: It's in the nature of PKCS5 padding that 1 to 16 bytes are added to the plaintext and therefore to the ciphertext. When decrypting those bytes got removed and the decrypted length has to be shorter.